# ListView with two columns

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I need your advice. I have a list, but I need to divide it into two columns. In the left column are all even elements of the list (0,2,4,6 ...), and the right all the odd elements.
I thought it was possible as that implemented using `GridView`, but it turns out everything in a single column.
If you can give an obvious example, or a reference to the solution of this problem.
I need something like this:
[image]

Comment: check this link set numColumn = 2 and apply your logic http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Comment: This is best done using a RecyclerView with the Grid Layout Manager. It's easy to implement and very efficient. Check this out https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 3):

change list view into grid view

insert below code on grid-view ;

```
    android:numColumns="2"
```